# Преобразовать строку [a,b,[c,d]] в стандартный JSON вида ["a","b",["c","d"]]?

Tags: c++, json, qt, c++11, парсер

Какими готовыми библиотеками воспользоваться?

То есть при вводе для строк не использовать кавычки и преобразовать в стандартный `JSON`, так как уже есть готовые библиотеки для парсования `JSON`-на.

Подойдет и прямое парсование в `QMap<QVariant>`

**Внимание!** Нужна **НЕ** библиотека для парсинга правильного `JSON`-а, а библиотека парсинга строк, **НЕ** являющихся правильным `JSON`-ом

Например вот фрагмент, который парсит нормальный `JSON`:

```
QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson("[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]");
QJsonArray arr = doc.array();
QJsonValue value = arr.at(0);
qDebug() << "value:" << value.toString();
```

Вывод: `value: "a"`

Мой случай:

```
QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson("[a,b,c]");
QJsonArray arr = doc.array();
QJsonValue value = arr.at(0);
qDebug() << "value:" << value.toString();
```

Вывод: `value: ""`

То есть мне нужно спарсовать строку `"[a,b,c]"` вместо `"[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]"`

Comment: в Qt есть библиотека для работы с json. Она не подходит? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html

Comment: @evilnw она корректно работает с правильной строкой json, когда все значения (кроме числовых и логических) взяты в кавычки. В случае, например, строки `[a,b,c]`, то есть без кавычек, библиотека не парсит

Comment: Заменить каждую запятую и каждую квадратную скобку на тот же символ, но обрамлённый кавычками. Удалить две кавычки подряд. Удалить начальную и конечную кавычки.

Comment: @Akina а, нет, сейчас попробую...

Comment: Какие строки следует считать строками? Должны ли `a b`, `a b"`, `a "b"`, `1` превратиться в `"a b"`, `"a b\""`, `"a \"b\""`, `"1"`? Как экранируется запятая? Квадратные скобки внутри таких строк?

Comment: @vp_arth нет, только без пробелов

Comment: @Akina оформите в виде ответа, я приму

Comment: @asianirish Сделал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Заменить каждую запятую и каждую квадратную скобку на тот же символ, но обрамлённый кавычками.
2. Удалить две кавычки подряд.
3. Удалить начальную и конечную кавычки.

Answer (score 0):

Очень хорошая библиотека NLohmann Json : Json for Modern C++. Скачивается с github: https://github.com/nlohmann/json Ваша задача, насколько я понимаю, решабельна в рамках данной библиотеки. Там есть примеры, есть материал для изучения, сделана она неплохо. Для Вашего поекта достаточно будет только проинклудить один хедер. Написана она на современном диалекте C++. Есть поддержка конвертации json-data в/из данных в виде STL контейнеров, C++14 строк и проч. Отмечу только, что эта библиотека написана не для скоростной работы, а для простой, для скорости используйте, например, Rapid Json.

Comment: парсит ли эта библиотека строку вида `[a,b,[c,d]]` (JSON без кавычек)?